# GTB6 in http_user_agent

Tags: headers

One of the users on our website reports the following HTTP_USER_AGENT:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0;
>   Windows NT 5.1; GTB6; .NET CLR
>   1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 3.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)

I cannot figure out what the GTB6 bit means.  Google searches are pointless.  Can someone explain what GTB6 means and, ideally, point me to a website that *explains* each part of the user agent, for the uncommon and infrequently seen parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [UserAgentString.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/Internet%20Explorer7.0_id_14276.php), GTB6 means the user has Google Toolbar installed on her IE. That site should also help you decipher other symbols on the user agent string, by the way.

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I was looking for.